# How to call a class, Java - Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, class, while-loop

I'm making a text based gladiator combat game. The problem I'm having is that it's not going into the other class when I try to call it. This is what I have.

**Main Class**

```
if (fill.equals("1")) {
    arena = true;
    while (arena == true) {
        System.out.println("You travel to the arena.");
        fill = scan.next();
        System.out.println("Vanguard: Welcome!");
        System.out.println("1) Enter the arena.");
        System.out.println("2) Exit the arena.");
        fill = scan.next();
        if (fill.equals("1")) {
            System.out.println("Vanguard: These are the available matches:");
            if (rank == "Rookie") {
                System.out.println("1) Snow");
                System.out.println("2) Blaze");
                System.out.println("3) Ember");
                fill = scan.next();

                if (fill.equals("1")) {
                    System.out.println("You with to battle Snow? Y/N");
                    fill = scan.next();
                    fill = fill.toLowerCase();
                    if (fill.equals("y")) {
                        enemy = "Snow";
                        enemyhealth = 35;
                        enemydamage = enemydamrn.nextInt((7 - 5) + 1) + 5;
                        System.out.println("You go to the arena to prepare with snow.");

                        Battle Battle = new Battle();
                    }       
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**When I type "y" into the scanner, it will just restart at the while statement, instead of going to the class.**

I would appreciate any help I can get with this. I'm pretty new to java, I've been coding with it for about 1.5 months and I would like to be able to find out this issue. I hope any of you could help me! ^_^/

Comment: Where do you set `arena = false` ? This seems the logical way to exit the while loop.

Comment: what do you expect `Battle Battle = new Battle()` to do?

Comment: funny that you would use `fill.equals("1")` but `rank == "Rookie"`

Comment: Simply creating an instance of a class doesn't produce whatever functionality you may be looking for. The instance is essentially a pointer to grab functionality from that class. You have to use that pointer.

Answer (score 1):

When you say

```
Battle Battle = new Battle();
```

you construct a new instance of `Battle` with a really unfortunate name. I suggest you try

```
Battle battle = new Battle();
```

and then (unless you do everything in the `Battle` constructor, which I would *not* recommend) you need to call the method you want to execute on your `Battle` instance like

```
battle.someMethod();
```

Also,

```
if (rank == "Rookie") {
```

is not going to work for comparing `String`(s). That's reference equality (not value). You need to test `String` equality like

```
if (rank.equals("Rookie")) {
```

Comment: plus 1 for instructing OP on the camelCasing java convention for the `battle` object.  though it might be worth noting, that you could leave it be and NOT call a method. have everything in the constructor of `Battle`

Comment: @OP maybe something like: `while (battle.isActive()) {...}` rather than having it in the constructor